# How to handle sent data to server in express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, post, xmlhttprequest

I am sending this post request from my `index.js` to my `app.js` (on a click event):

```
var data = {
   name: "Sarah",
   age: "21"
};
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", "/", true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    xhr.send(JSON.stringify({
        data: data
    }));
```

Then in my `app.js`, I have this:

```
app.post('/', function(req, res) {

    if(req.xhr) {
        console.log(req.body.name); 
    }

 });
```

But nothing is console logged and after a while? I have body-parser installed also. Anything missing?

I also get this error message in the console after a while:

```
POST http://localhost:8080/ 0 ()
```

Comment: You aren't sending a response though? `res.end()`. Or send a status code.

Comment: I guess it should be `req.body.data.name`. And `res.send()` also is needed

Comment: You can check out the `req.body` object by snippet `console.log(req.body);`, then you can see `body` object does not have any field called `name`, the `body` have only one field - `data`. Another way, you take the change on client side `xhr.send(JSON.stringify(data);`

Comment: Adding res.send() worked. Thanks @dhilt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So from the comments, I made this change in my `app.js`:

```
app.post('/', function(req, res) {

    res.send(req.body.data);

});
```

Then in my `index.js`:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", "/", true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    xhr.send(JSON.stringify({
        data: data
    }));

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
      if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
        if (xhr.status === 200) {
          console.log(xhr.responseText);
        } else {
          alert('There was a problem with the request.');
        }
      }
    }
```

Basically, I was missing the `res.send()` initially. And when that information is sent then I was able to `console.log` the response on my `index.js`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add if condition
Try this

```
app.post('/', function(req, res) { console.log(req.body.code);  });
```